# How to troubleshoot 3rd party service start failure on windows server 2016 standard edition

Tags: windows, service

I have a windows server 2016 standard edition 64-bit machine. The machine is up to date and has the latest security updates.
On this machine I have a 3rd party service called Couchba*emphasized text*seServer which is the main service of a 3rd party product called Couchbase server version 7.1.1 enterprise edition.

The service fails to start if the service log on user is set to a normal local user (no admin. rights), the service simply stops with this error message in the windows system event log:

> Erlang machine stopped instantly (distribution name conflict?). The
> service is not restarted, ignoring OnFail option.

If I put the service user into the local admin group then the service starts successfully.

The 3rd party service doesn't log anything before it fails. I also cannot analyze the process crash dump cause I don't have the debug binaries. In other words the 3rd party tool doesn't help me analyzing the error.

My hope is that there is a another way in windows that helps identify why the service fails to start.

Comment: Run SysInternals ProcMon to identify the resource that it is failing on (access denied).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: Nothing shows up in ProcMon. I filtered on Result contains "denied".

Comment: Have you checked the Application Event Logs? Otherwise contact their support to help troubleshoot.